# Оптимальная архитектура бд для интернет магазина

Tags: структуры-данных, база-данных, архитектура, sql

Заезженный вопрос, но все же. Есть интернет-магазин компьютерной техники. Известная проблема это свойства, параметры техники. У каждого свои - смысла городить в одну таблицу нет. После гугла и сотни статей, пришел к выводу что UDA оптимальный вариант.
3 таблицы:

1. products(общая информация о товаре, название, цена и т.д.)
2. prod_attributes(свойства, параметры)
3. prod_values(связь свойств и характеристиками товара).

Подумываю может разбить свойства и характеристики по таблицам с прявязкой к типу продукции аля notebook_attr и notebook_values, т.к. типов продукции не более 10.

Что посоветуют знатоки? Может кто-то уже разрабатывал архитектуру именно реляционной базы для стандартного простенького интернет-магазина аля www.techno-city.by. И поделится своим опытом.

П.С. Заранее прошу про NOSQL не писать. Не могу поверить что все мелкие онлайн-шопы на монго и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите структуру [DotPlant2](https://github.com/devgroup-ru/dotplant2) - это CMS для интернет-магазинов на Yii.

Если кратко, то структура примерно такая:

- product - основные свойства продукта, цена, связка с дочерними продуктами(модификациями) через parent_id
- product_eav - то, что можно хранить как EAV и по чему вряд ли не потребуется искать/фильтровать
- product_property - характеристики товаров, не принимающие множественные значения. Колонки добавляются динамически, когда задаётся новое возможное свойство в базе. По сути table inheritance. Минус подхода - избыточность при наличии большого количества разных по набору свойств товаров.
- property_static_values - список возможных значений для свойств типа "выбор из списка"
- object_static_values - сопоставление товара и ID значения из предыдущей таблицы

На мой взгляд - это самая оптимальная структура для разнородных данных, когда кроме MySQL ничего нет.

Но если есть возможность, лучше использовать простую структуру для хранения(как у вас) и какой-нибудь elastic search или mongodb для фильтрации/поиска.

Answer (score -1):

То, что Вы описали, это самое обычное решение данной задачи с точки зрения реляционных баз данных.

Но оно, на мой взгляд, избыточно.

Я Вам больше скажу - для этого вообще база данных не нужна. Недавно сталкивались с сходной проблемой. Думали-думали какая БД, какая структура.

А потом прекратили думать и посчитали: несколько тысяч товаров, описание свойств каждого занимает сколько-то там (уже не помню) байт в среднем. И в целом все наши описания свойств (аналог вашей таблицы prod_attributes) товаров укладываются в менее чем в 200 килобайт.

Мыслим дальше: данные меняются крайне редко, изоляции транзакций не нужно, данные используются крайне часто (по сути - это самая востребованная информация для сайта интернет-магазина).

Данные можно организовать в виде удобной для конкретного языка программирования структуры (массив, список, кортеж, список списков и пр. и пр.) и займет это совсем немного места (ну что для современных серверов сотни килобайт оперативной памяти).

Реализовали такую систему: при загрузке веб-приложения с диска из обычного текстового файла считываются свойства товаров и помещаются в оперативную память в виде удобной для дальнейшей работы структуры.

При обновлении свойств (которое происходит раз в сутки) дергается специальный URI и происходит повторное чтение файла с данными и перезаполнение этой структуры.

Повторяю: база данных для данной задачи вообще не нужна.

Comment: А как же фильтрация?

Comment: @Bethrezen С помощью LINQ или Stream API.